# How can I query for a specific field inside a list of objects in mongo?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I have a collection that looks something like this:

```
{
    "Field1": "Value1",
    "Field2": "Value2",
    "Field3": "Value3",
    "Field4": "Value4",
    "Field5": [
        {
            "SubFieldA1": "subValueA1",
            "SubFieldA2": "subValueA2"
        },
        {
            "SubFieldB1": "subValueB1",
            "SubFieldB2": "subValueB2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am writing an aggregate query that needs to display the following information based on a few filter criteria:

```
{
    "Field1": "Value1",
    "SubFieldB2": "subValueB2"
}
```

This is my query:

```
db.Collection_Name.aggregate([
    { $match: { "Field1": "FilterValue1" } },
    { $match: { "Field2": "FilterValue2" } },
    { $project: { "Field1" : 1, "subValueB2": { $arrayElemAt: ["$Field5", 1] } } }
])
```

This gives me the second element of the `Field5` as a whole but I want only a specific field of it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: add stage ? `{ "$addFields": { "subFieldB2": "$subFieldB2.SubFieldB2" } }`

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [`"$getField"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/)? Like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_LDYp496FEf)?